I do not see a ground wire to stake at the meter pole. Is this a utility problem?
I do not see a ground wire to stake at the meter pole.
Is this a utility problem?
Do I have to remove the smart meter to add a ground?

Utilities get quite nasty when people pull their meters.

Is there a transformer there?

You need to start at your main breaker panel. Depending on a number of factors, that could be a big box in your basement or garage or outside or a small box at your meter. Generally, but not always, this will have one large breaker (e.g., 200A) that shuts off power to the entire house. Assuming you find the main panel, that is where you should find a ground wire which will usually (unless something isn't right) connect to ground rods ("stake at the meter pole", except it doesn't have to be at the meter pole) and/or cold water pipe.
If you are not sure, upload pictures of whatever breaker panels you find and we can usually figure it out.

Will do tomorrow.

Everything ahead of the service point belongs to the utility. Everything after that is yours.
Normally, the service point is ahead of the meter socket on the service mast or service pole.
The utility usually drives a ground rod at the utility pole with the transformer and grounds the neutral at that location, but that transformer may serve several houses and not be located next to yours.
It is your responsibility to drive a separate ground rod or 2 in some cases at your service. Then your service will be bonded to that ground rod and the neutral at your service will also be bonded to the ground at that point. They handle everything ahead of your service drop or lateral connection. Do not worry about their part.
To remove the utility meter you will need to schedule a shut down with the utility and they will pull the fuse to your service or remove your meter themselves and normally return at the end of the day to reconnect your service.

In my very limited experience (Pepco in Maryland), with a licensed electrician they will let the electrician put the meter back in and then return at their convenience to tag it. But I suspect they are stricter about things when a homeowner is doing their own work (which is allowed in my area under certain constraints).

I used to pull my own meter and attach my generator with clips at my old house but that was before smart meters. The meter will "phone home" if it loses power and the big trucks will show up. They might let you reinstall it after an upgrade and then tag it like you say when they get back there.

The key is letting them know at the beginning. Of course, if that beginning is when power is out for the whole area then I suppose it gets a little more complicated - and at least they should be happy then that you pulled the meter rather than backfeeding into the broken grid while they're fixing it.
